# How to do a getNearest query in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am looking for a way to execute a geospatial query, getNearest function in Neo4j, very similar to what RethinkDB have here - https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#get_nearest

For example, I have nodes with label Home and Hospitals. Each of those nodes have latitude and longitude properties. I want to get a nearest hospital to a home. Is it possible in Neo4j? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension called [neo4j spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) that provides exactly such kind of functionality.

Be sure to read through the [reference manual](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial).